# Getting the value of all session variables in IIS

Tags: asp.net, variables, session, iis

I have a web application developed in asp.net
The application has a "logon" portal where I record users logging on. However, I don't really know when they have exited the web application as they could just shut down the browser, rather than using the "logout" option. As IIS keeps track of session variables for a finite period when users logon, I thought a really useful option would be to use my ASP.net application to interrogate IIS for the value of all session variables, thus telling me who is still active via their session variables.

This could be very useful when it comes to dropping in an upgrade to the website and generally looking at the use of the site.

Thanks

session object. But it only tells me about the current user.

Comment: A common beginner mistake is to assume that IIS knows everything. However, sessions are fully implemented by ASP.NET framework and not visible to IIS at all. Depending on the session mode you configure, you might or might not have a way to query all active sessions. Thus, I suggest you first learn which session mode is currently being used in your project.

Comment: you could try sql session state mode in iis https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178586(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN